# openstack Python sdk : user-data to execute startup script

Tags: python, sdk, openstack, user-data

I try to execute a startup script when I create a new instance (with python openstack sdk), but it doesn't work. I read some docs but I can't say if i have to use a file, encode or not in base 64.

My command looks like this :

```
cloud.compute.create_server(name=name, ....  image_id=image.id, user-data=XXXXXXX )
```

Could you please provide me a working example of user-data arg ?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved : https://gist.github.com/arnaudmorin/72bff355d9d42ed9aff8dfecd7f3f362

```
userdata = base64.b64encode("#!/bin/bash\ntouch /root/test".encode("utf-8")).decode('utf-8')
```